# Durable function - activity function max. time out

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

What is the max. time out period of activity function which orchestrator function calls in  Durable function on consumption hosting plan?

Comment: I think its 5 min by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity function is similar to any function invocation and is bound by the [same timeout durations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) depending on the plan that they are deployed to.

In case of the consumption plan, its **5 minutes** by default and can be configured up to **10 minutes** by setting the [`functionTimeout` property in `host.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout).